# Facebook Request Dialog, bad receive experience

Tags: facebook

I'm newbie with the facebook API, I'm sorry if it's a silly question.
I'm using the facebook request dialog with the direct URL method.

When I send the request it seems works well, but I can't get the receive experience explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/).

When recipients receive notifications, at the beginning seems correct because his bookmark counter increments with a new notification, but after a couple of seconds (or less) the counter disappears and if the user clicks in notifications he doensn't see the notifications, it's empty.

The URL I use is this:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=339270982866129&message=testing&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://noteboardapp.com/api/sendRequestFb.php

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you.
Oscar.

Comment: User-to-User requests only work for canvas apps – is yours one (or at least _has_ canvas URLs set up where the user can actually see some content)?

Comment: I've tried to put a URL in "App on Facebook" in "Canvas Page" to convert the app to canvas app. And now the request doesn't dissapear, but when the user clicks to go to the app (it's a normal web) then is showed this message: "Secure browsing is not supported - This application does not yet support secure browsing (HTTPS)." What does it mean?

Comment: Well I suppose I have to add a https url of my web, but I don't have secure protocol. Then I can't use my web like a canvas facebook app and I can't use request system?

Comment: Correct, canvas apps must support SSL.

Comment: Ok, thank you, then I understand, but I think a couple of weeks ago it worked without to do the app like a canvas one. I want to mark the question like solved but there is not the solved check.

Comment: Added an answer to summarize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User-to-User requests only work for canvas apps (or iOS/android), as stated in the docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/:

> *"Requests are only available for Desktop Canvas, iOS and Android apps. Accepting a request on Canvas will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request."*

So you would have to add a canvas tab for your web app to be able to receive requests. But be aware that canvas apps whose only purpose is to redirect the user outside of facebook.com are against platform policies.